# Fixed height elements in tables

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am putting together an HTML Email (say a prayer for me!) and I'm trying to have each block a fixed height. Or at least start in the same position.

You can see in the attached that the heights are disproportionate and not aligned.

How do I fix this issue?

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/smu0gyx7/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">  <!-- Disable auto-scale in iOS 10 Mail entirely -->
    <title></title> <!-- The title tag shows in email notifications, like Android 4.4. -->

    <!-- Web Font / @font-face : BEGIN -->
    <!-- NOTE: If web fonts are not required, lines 10 - 27 can be safely removed. -->

    <!-- Desktop Outlook chokes on web font references and defaults to Times New Roman, so we force a safe fallback font. -->
    <!--[if mso]>
        <style>
            * {
                font-family: sans-serif !important;
            }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- All other clients get the webfont reference; some will render the font and others will silently fail to the fallbacks. More on that here: http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2015/02/webfont-support-in-email/ -->
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <!-- insert web font reference, eg: <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <!-- Web Font / @font-face : END -->

    <!-- CSS Reset : BEGIN -->
    <style>

        /* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */
        /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0 auto !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
        * {
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }

        /* What it does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */
        div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
            margin: 0 !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
        table,
        td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
        table {
            border-spacing: 0 !important;
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            table-layout: fixed !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
        }
        table table table {
            table-layout: auto;
        }

        /* What it does: Prevents Windows 10 Mail from underlining links despite inline CSS. Styles for underlined links should be inline. */
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        /* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */
        img {
            -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
        }

        /* What it does: A work-around for email clients meddling in triggered links. */
        *[x-apple-data-detectors],  /* iOS */
        .unstyle-auto-detected-links *,
        .aBn {
            border-bottom: 0 !important;
            cursor: default !important;
            color: inherit !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            font-size: inherit !important;
            font-family: inherit !important;
            font-weight: inherit !important;
            line-height: inherit !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Prevents Gmail from displaying a download button on large, non-linked images. */
        .a6S {
           display: none !important;
           opacity: 0.01 !important;
       }
       /* If the above doesn't work, add a .g-img class to any image in question. */
       img.g-img + div {
           display: none !important;
       }

        /* What it does: Removes right gutter in Gmail iOS app: https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/issues/89  */
        /* Create one of these media queries for each additional viewport size you'd like to fix */

        /* iPhone 4, 4S, 5, 5S, 5C, and 5SE */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 374px) {
            .email-container {
                min-width: 320px !important;
            }
        }
        /* iPhone 6, 6S, 7, 8, and X */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 413px) {
            .email-container {
                min-width: 375px !important;
            }
        }
        /* iPhone 6+, 7+, and 8+ */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) {
            .email-container {
                min-width: 414px !important;
            }
        }

    </style>
    <!-- CSS Reset : END -->
     <!-- Reset list spacing because Outlook ignores much of our inline CSS. -->
     <!--[if mso]>
     <style type="text/css">
          ul,
          ol {
               margin: 0 !important;
          }
          li {
               margin-left: 30px !important;
          }
          li.list-item-first {
               margin-top: 0 !important;
          }
          li.list-item-last {
               margin-bottom: 10px !important;
          }
     </style>
     <![endif]-->

    <!-- Progressive Enhancements : BEGIN -->
    <style>

        /* What it does: Hover styles for buttons */
        .button-td,
        .button-a {
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
        }
         .button-td-primary:hover,
         .button-a-primary:hover {
             background: #555555 !important;
             border-color: #555555 !important;
         }

        /* Media Queries */
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

            .email-container {
                width: 100% !important;
                margin: auto !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces elements to resize to the full width of their container. Useful for resizing images beyond their max-width. */
            .fluid {
                max-width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */
            .stack-column,
            .stack-column-center {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                direction: ltr !important;
            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .stack-column-center {
                text-align: center !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Generic utility class for centering. Useful for images, buttons, and nested tables. */
            .center-on-narrow {
                text-align: center !important;
                display: block !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
                float: none !important;
            }
            table.center-on-narrow {
                display: inline-block !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Adjust typography on small screens to improve readability */
            .email-container p {
                font-size: 17px !important;
            }
        }

    </style>
    <!-- Progressive Enhancements : END -->

     <style>
     @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins);
     /*  Place your css style here  */
     h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,li,ol,ul {
          font-family:'Poppins',sans-serif
     }
     a {
          color:#e30b18;
          font-weight:bold;
     }
     </style>

    <!-- What it does: Makes background images in 72ppi Outlook render at correct size. -->
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:AllowPNG/>
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<!--
     The email background color (#222222) is defined in three places:
     1. body tag: for most email clients
     2. center tag: for Gmail and Inbox mobile apps and web versions of Gmail, GSuite, Inbox, Yahoo, AOL, Libero, Comcast, freenet, Mail.ru, Orange.fr
     3. mso conditional: For Windows 10 Mail
-->
<body width="100%" style="margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; background-color: #222222;">    <center style="width: 100%; background-color: #222222;">
    <!--[if mso | IE]>
    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background-color: #222222;">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <![endif]-->

        <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : BEGIN -->
        <div style="display: none; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all; font-family: sans-serif;">
            (Optional) This text will appear in the inbox preview, but not the email body. It can be used to supplement the email subject line or even summarize the email's contents. Extended text preheaders (~490 characters) seems like a better UX for anyone using a screenreader or voice-command apps like Siri to dictate the contents of an email. If this text is not included, email clients will automatically populate it using the text (including image alt text) at the start of the email's body.
        </div>
        <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : END -->

        <!-- Create white space after the desired preview text so email clients don’t pull other distracting text into the inbox preview. Extend as necessary. -->
        <!-- Preview Text Spacing Hack : BEGIN -->
        <div style="display: none; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all; font-family: sans-serif;">
             &zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;
        </div>
        <!-- Preview Text Spacing Hack : END -->
               
          <!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->
          <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600" style="margin: 0 auto;" class="email-container">
    
            <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : END -->

             <!-- 2 Even Columns : BEGIN -->
             <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="height:200px; padding: 10px; background-color: #ffffff;">
                         <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                   <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                                   <td class="stack-column-center">
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="">
                                             <tr>
                                                  <td style=" font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                       <p style="margin: 0;color:black;background-color:#F1F1F1;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="color:#e30b18">DAY 1</span><br></span><br><span style="font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum</span><br><br>Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.<br><br><a href="#">READ MORE</a></p>
                                                  </td>
                                             </tr>
                                        </table>
                                   </td>
                                   <!-- Column : END -->
                                   <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                                   <td class="stack-column-center">
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="">
                                             <tr>
                                                  <td style=" font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                       <p style="margin: 0;color:black;background-color:#F1F1F1;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="color:#e30b18">DAY 2</span><br></span><br><span style="font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;">Lorem ipsum</span><br><br>Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.<br><br><a href="#">READ MORE</a></p>
                                                  </td>
                                             </tr>
                                        </table>
                                   </td>
                                   <!-- Column : END -->
                              </tr>
                         </table>
                    </td>
               </tr>
               <!-- 2 Even Columns : END -->

             <!-- 2 Even Columns : BEGIN -->
             <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="height:200px; padding: 10px; background-color: #ffffff;">
                         <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                   <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                                   <td class="stack-column-center">
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="">
                                             <tr>
                                                  <td style=" font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                       <p style="margin: 0;color:black;background-color:#F1F1F1;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="color:#e30b18">DAY 3</span><br></span><br><span style="font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;">Lorem ipsum dolor</span><br><br>Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.<br><br><a href="#">READ MORE</a></p>
                                                  </td>
                                             </tr>
                                        </table>
                                   </td>
                                   <!-- Column : END -->
                                   <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                                   <td class="stack-column-center">
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="">
                                             <tr>
                                                  <td style=" font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                       <p style="margin: 0;color:black;background-color:#F1F1F1;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="color:#e30b18">DAY 4</span><br></span><br><span style="font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</span><br><br>Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.<br><br><a href="#">READ MORE</a></p>
                                                  </td>
                                             </tr>
                                        </table>
                                   </td>
                                   <!-- Column : END -->
                              </tr>
                         </table>
                    </td>
               </tr>
               <!-- 2 Even Columns : END -->

             <!-- 2 Even Columns : BEGIN -->
             <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="height:200px; padding: 10px; background-color: #ffffff;">
                         <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                   <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                                   <td class="stack-column-center">
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="">
                                             <tr>
                                                  <td style=" font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                       <p style="margin: 0;color:black;background-color:#F1F1F1;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="color:#e30b18">DAY 5</span><br></span><br><span style="font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;">Lorem ipsum dolor</span><br><br>Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.<br><br><a href="#">READ MORE</a></p>
                                                  </td>
                                             </tr>
                                        </table>
                                   </td>
                                   <!-- Column : END -->
                                   <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                                   <td class="stack-column-center">
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="">
                                             <tr>
                                                  <td style=" font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                       <p style="margin: 0;color:black;background-color:#F1F1F1;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="color:#e30b18">DAY 6</span><br></span><br><span style="font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</span><br><br>Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.<br><br><a href="#">READ MORE</a></p>
                                                  </td>
                                             </tr>
                                        </table>
                                   </td>
                                   <!-- Column : END -->
                              </tr>
                         </table>
                    </td>
               </tr>
               <!-- 2 Even Columns : END -->

             <!-- 2 Even Columns : BEGIN -->
             <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="padding: 10px; background-color: #ffffff;">
                         <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                   <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                                   <td class="stack-column-center">
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="">
                                             <tr>
                                                  <td style=" font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                       <p style="margin: 0;color:black;background-color:#F1F1F1;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="color:#e30b18">DAY 7</span><br></span><br><span style="font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;">Lorem ipsum dolor</span><br><br>Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.<br><br><a href="#">READ MORE</a></p>
                                                  </td>
                                             </tr>
                                        </table>
                                   </td>
                                   <!-- Column : END -->
                                   <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                                   <td class="stack-column-center">
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="">
                                             <tr>
                                                  <td style=" font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"></td>
                                             </tr>
                                        </table>
                                   </td>
                                   <!-- Column : END -->
                              </tr>
                         </table>
                    </td>
               </tr>
               <!-- 2 Even Columns : END -->

         </table>
         <!-- Email Body : END -->

         <!-- Full Bleed Background Section : BEGIN -->
         <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color: black;">
             <tr>
                 <td valign="top">
                     <div style="max-width: 600px; margin: auto;" class="email-container">
                         <!--[if mso]>
                         <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600" align="center">
                         <tr>
                         <td>
                         <![endif]-->
                         <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                             <tr>
                                 <td style="padding: 20px; text-align: left; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #ffffff;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                                     <p style="margin: 0;"><unsubscribe>unsubscribe</unsubscribe></p>
                                 </td>
                             </tr>
                         </table>
                         <!--[if mso]>
                         </td>
                         </tr>
                         </table>
                         <![endif]-->
                     </div>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
         <!-- Full Bleed Background Section : END -->

    <!--[if mso | IE]>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <![endif]-->
    </center>
</body>
</html>
​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the snippet you have provided, the height issue is only because you have different content on the second cell, where heading is shorter than the first one. So if you must have same height div irrespective of the content you have to set a equal height for the cells.

Comment: That's right. Is there no way to fix the height of the elements? So even if we have different content, it'll be a fixed height?

Comment: One quick would be you can set a min height for your element, so that all the cell element will have same height, but it should be the height of the tallest div you have, in this example if you set a min-height to your p element you can see everything has same height.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can have height fixed to some value:

```
    td {
        height:100px;
        width:100%;
    }
```

This works for the desktop view. Similarly you can manipulate the media-query for mobile devices.